# Vimeo videos do not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vimeo, react-player

I'm using react-player lib for loading videos on my app, but vimeo videos sometimes won't work on mobile devices. Youtube videos are good, so far as I've tested and vimeo always work on desktop.
I don't get any errors on the console when the video breaks, and if I keep refreshing the app, sometimes it will load and work just fine.
This is what I have for the player:

```
<ReactPlayer
  config={{ vimeo: { preload: true } }}
  url={slice.videoUrl}
  width="100%"
  height="100%"
  controls
/>
```

[this is how the video looks like when it breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7bM4.png)

Does anyone has any suggestions of what might be the issue or how to fix? I found a lot of people complaining about this issue, but they had errors on the console, which I don't have

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @DSCH I have no console errors